# Content not appear in body

Tags: xss, javascript

I have a file `a.html`, which has the following content:

```
<script>
var x=document.URL.substring(document.URL.indexOf('#')+1);
document.write(x);  
alert(document.body.innerHTML);
</script>
<body>

</body>
```

When I am browsing to `a.html#somevalueh;alert(1)</script>`, why only `"somevalueh;alert(1)"` but not the `</script>` portion  appeared inside the body?

I am using chrome btw. Is it a feature that prevent XSS? Does it work by stripping `</script>` or ...?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about Information security within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: @LucasKauffman But it is about XSS?

Comment: I didn't read your question correctly, I assumed it was a general JavaScript one, sorry my bad! Added an answer :)

Comment: Maybe anyway more over belongs on SO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome has default protection against Reflective XSS attacks. In Chrome there is a flag with which you can start the browser. If you start the browser with this flag, you can do what you want:

```
--disable-web-security
```

Comment: Thanks! But I am having difficulty is turning it off, the question is here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85044/cannot-turn-off-xss-filter-in-chrome